# Sorting Excel with openpyxl

Tags: openpyxl

My English is not well,sorry about that.
I am trying to sort a sheet using openpyxl and Python. I have read the documents and I don't quite understand this page. I am expecting to sort my excel file by some columns,at frist sort by column A,then by column B,then by cloumn C and last by column F.My problem is how to use add_sort_condition and add_filter_column these two ways,just the simple way would be great.If i can get an example,that's help me a lot!

```
wb_read = openpyxl.load_workbook(filename)
sheet_read = wb_read.get_active_sheet()
sheet_read.auto_filter.ref = 'A3:Q40000'
"""sheet_read.auto_filter.add_filter.column(2,['id'],blank=False) Didn't work
sheet_read.auto_filter.add_sort_condition('A') How and Where to use condition?
sheet_read.auto_filter.add_sort_condition('A3:Q40000') It seems didn't work again"""
wb_read.save('sorted.xlsx')
```

By the way,If i want to sort,Do I have to use auto_filter?

Comment: You should always provide some of your own code and then point to specific parts that you don't understand.

Comment: Sorry about that,I just don't know how to mark about code.I have modify my question,It should be look better than before.

Comment: You do realise that openpyxl itself doesn't actually sort but just creates the structures in the file so that Excel adds the dropdowns for sorting and filtering? If you actually want to sort then I suggest you use Pandas.

Comment: Oh, I see!I don't know how to use Pandas.Let me read  the documents and see if it's work.ths a lot!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again.After learing Pandas,I realise the power of pandas in sorting,its very simple and useful.That satisfied all my sorting requirements,Thank you again!If I have any questions can't understand in the future, can I ask you again?